# Multiple AuthFactories in Dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

I want to use two different authfactories in dropwizard, Basic and OAuth. Like this :-

```
BasicAuthFactory<UserA> authFactory = new BasicAuthFactory<UserA>(new  IngestionConsoleAuthenticator(),"SUPER SECRET STUFF", UserA.class);

OAuthFactory<UserB> authFactory2 = new OAuthFactory<UserB>(new PSVAppAuthenticator(), "Secret", UserB.class);

environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(authFactory));
environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(authFactory2));
```

The resources with `@Auth UserA` works fine, but with `@Auth UserB` are reachable without any authentication. How can i make both work simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

> http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/auth.html#chained-factories
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration,
>                 Environment environment) {
>     ChainedAuthFactory<User> chainedFactory = new ChainedAuthFactory<>(
>             new BasicAuthFactory<>(new ExampleBasicAuthenticator(), "SUPER SECRET STUFF", User.class),
>             new OAuthFactory<>(new ExampleOAuthAuthenticator(), "SUPER SECRET STUFF", User.class));
>     environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(chainedFactory));
> }
> ```
>
> For this to work properly, all chained factories must produce the same
>   type of principal, here User.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The dropwizard documentation is good, so please just read the example code there. Example below is from [Dropwizard 1.0.0 Documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/auth.html)

```
@Override
public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration,
                Environment environment) {
    AuthFilter basicCredentialAuthFilter = new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<>()
            .setAuthenticator(new ExampleBasicAuthenticator())
            .setAuthorizer(new ExampleAuthorizer())
            .setPrefix("Basic")
            .buildAuthFilter();

    AuthFilter oauthCredentialAuthFilter = new OAuthCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<>()
            .setAuthenticator(new ExampleOAuthAuthenticator())
            .setAuthorizer(new ExampleAuthorizer())
            .setPrefix("Bearer")
            .buildAuthFilter();

    List<AuthFilter> filters = Lists.newArrayList(basicCredentialAuthFilter, oauthCredentialAuthFilter);
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new ChainedAuthFilter(filters)));
    environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    //If you want to use @Auth to inject a custom Principal type into your resource
    environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
}
```